# How to get Auto Increment Value of a MySQL table using php?

Tags: php, mysqli, auto-increment

I can use the following mySQL query to get the AUTO_INCREMENT Value.

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT  FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'node_revision'  and table_schema = 'myDatabase'
```

But I can't get it using php.  please help.  I want solution for **mysqli**

[image: PHPMy Admin Shows the Auto Increment Value]

**Here PHP code:**

```
$OBdb = new MySQLDB(DBHost, DBUser, DBPassword, DBName);
$sql= "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT  FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'node_revision'  and table_schema = 'mydatabase'";
$result =$OBdb->query($sql);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: _But I can't get it using php_  Can't get it how?

Comment: Why can't you run that same SQL from PHP?

Comment: i don't get anything. that's why I posted question here.  I am not inserting anything. I just want to get it.

Comment: @barnamah What exactly do you mean by "I don't get anything". Does the `var_dump()` gets executed? Do you get error messages?

Comment: You are not fetching any value

Comment: Wondering : MySQLDB class comes from what ?  What error messages are you getting when running this php `program` ?

Comment: when running the code it print  bool(false)

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: who posted that top "the question answered"? it is NOT. I am looking for "Auto Increment" ID which is not in that page. Also I am not looking to insert and get ID.

Comment: @Dharman you didn't read or saw the image above. MYSQL has no issue. the exact query which retunes result using phpMyAdmin, I can't get the same thing using php code.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You didn't address our comments. What is `MySQLDB`? Are you actually using mysqli? If so, do you fetch the results of the query anywhere? Do you have mysqli error reporting enabled? Just because phpMyAdmin can execute the query doesn't mean that your application can too.